# Unable to retrieve entity tracked by context in foreach loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have got the primary key of the `Student` table using following code:

```
var stud_id = (from p in context.Students
                          where p.Student_Name == "Bruce"
                          select  p.Student_Id );
```

When I try to use `stud_id` to retrieve whole entity,with the following code:

```
Student requiredstud = new Student();
foreach (var p in stud_id)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(p);

            requiredObj = context.Students.Find(p);
            string tempObj = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString<Student>(requiredObj);
            Console.WriteLine(tempObj);

            }
```

it gives following exception on the line:

```
requiredObj = context.Students.Find(p);
```

[image]

How to solve this problem and get the details of that `student`

**Edit:**
    InnerException

is: `{"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."}`

Comment: click on `View Detail...` and see the inner exception, you may add it to your question

Comment: @Habib:Added InnerException

Answer (score 0):

Since you are iterating an `IQueryable` and trying to find the another student using the same `context`, you are getting the exception. You should do `.ToList` in your query to iterate it and get the records from the database. Later you can use the context in the foreach loop. So your query can be:

```
var stud_id = (from p in context.Students
                          where p.Student_Name == "Bruce"
                          select  p.Student_Id ).ToList();
```

Or

```
var stud_id = context.Students.Where(p=> p.Student_Name == "Bruce").ToList();
```

Comment: For var stud_id = context.Students.Where(p.Student_Name == "Bruce").ToList(); , it is giving error that p does not exixst in the current context.

Comment: @BhushanFirake, ohh, Missed a simple thing. check the edit It should have been `var stud_id = context.Students.Where(p=> p.Student_Name == "Bruce").ToList();`

Comment: :The specified parameter type 'University.Student' is not valid. Only scalar types, such as System.Int32, System.Decimal, System.DateTime, and System.Guid, are supported.

Comment: Same line as in the question